# ASP.NET controls are not disabling

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I'm trying to disable a panel on my page depending on what value the user selects from a drop down list, but apparently this isn't as simple as I thought it would be. My code looks something like this:

```
private void theList_SelectedIndexChanged(object o, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    panelOne.Enabled = false;
}
```

But it seems that when this method is reached, the only control that actually disables within `panelOne` is a date picker (telerik:RadDatePicker). The rest of the controls will only disable after I change the selection on a radio button that's also in the same panel. Does anyone have any clues as to what's going on? I'm using Telerik's RadControls, but I'm not sure if this problem is specific to their controls or whether it affects the other controls as well.

Here's the panel itself:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelOne" runat="server" >

    <!-- this disables -->
    <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdpDate" runat="server" />

    <!-- this doesn't disable -->
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" />

</asp:Panel>
```

All controls inside the panel disable if I set `panelOne.Enabled = False` inside `Page_Load()`, but that isn't what I'm looking for. The textbox simply needs to disable when the user selects a certain value from the drop down list.

**Update: I've found that adding the following to the aspx worked:**

```
<telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="txtTest" LoadingPanelID="pnlLoading" />
```

There's some weird behaviour if I do the above for the entire panel, so I have to do it for each control individually...

Comment: more code for panel will help

Comment: @user1848739 added the code but there's not much to show

Comment: try to make it disabled from aspx page itself. because its working fine for me! what is the theList?

Comment: @user1848739 i can disable it from the aspx page and also anywhere inside Page_Load, but i can't do it during runtime.

Comment: Did you try disabling individual controls?

Comment: @user1848739 seems that this is what i'll have to do. check my update on the original post.